# how to pass properties to a react-native component inside a tab navigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, tabnavigator

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {Button,FlatList,Text,View} from 'react-native';

class Recent extends Component<{}> {

  getData() {
      return ["Locked in room","Fell on the floor", "Need help with Stairs"];
  }
  render() {

    let {navigate} = this.props.navigation;


    console.log(this.props.user); // this line gives me undefined
    return (
        <FlatList
          style={{flex:1,width:"100%"}}
          data={this.getData()}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text onPress={()=>navigate("NextPage",{user:this.props.user})}>{item}</Text>}
        />
    );
  }
}

const RequestRouter = TabNavigator({
  Recent1: {screen: Recent},
  Recent2:{screen:Recent}
  }
);

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  render() {

    let {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    const user = this.props.navigation.state.params.user;

    return (
        <View style={{flex:1,flexDirection:"column"}}>
            <Button onPress={()=>navigate("NextPage",{user:user})}
                title="Go"
                accessibilityLabel="Go"
            />
            <View style={{width:"100%",flex:6,flexDirection:"column"}}>
            <RequestRouter user={user} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the `console.log(this.props.user);` inside the `class Recent extends Component` gives me an `undefined`.  This is because I don't know how to properly pass the `user` variable in the `App.render()` into the `Recent.render()`, since there is a `TabNavigator` that routes requests to the `Recent` class.

How do I pass the `user` variable from `App.render()` into `Recent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [screenProps](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html#navigator-props) to pass props to child component inside `TabNavigator` like this:

```
<RequestRouter screenProps={user} />
```

You can access it in child component by `this.props.screenProps.user`